# How to set DateTime format in IValueConverter and return string value?

Tags: c#, ivalueconverter

I want a specific format in `IValueConverter` and return a string. Like `"MMMyyyy"` How can I get this?

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var item = (DateTime)value;
    if (item != null)
    {
        return item.ToString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If you having datetime object in binding then you can use the stringformat of binding to have the output you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
     var item = (DateTime)value;
     if (item != null)
     {
         return item.ToString("MMMyyyy");
     }
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need an `IValueConverter` here? 
If you want this for a binding to display the databound `DateTime` with a specific format in WPF, you can use the `StringFormat` property of the `Binding`

[Article about `StringFormat`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx)

Comment: i am also thing about this one using stringformat will be more effective for him.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime`s overload for ToString() - ToString( string format ). Thus - you can write:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var item = (DateTime)value;
    if (item != null)
    {
        return item.ToString("MMMyyyy");
    }
    return null;
}
```

For more information have a look at this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You just simply need to add the format ToString as parameter

```
 return item.ToString("MMyyyy");
```